# How to wrap a div and a img in a display:flex container

Tags: css, flexbox, display, grid-layout

EDIT: You need to run the snippet in fullscreen.

I have a display: flex container with div element and other with img inside of it , both of them with 50% width. I want them when resizing below 800px width to be with 100% width of the screen and to wrap one after another on a new lines (flex-wrap) but still remain responsive as they were before the wrapping.

I tried, but I'm doing something wrong - when the screen is below 800px width the img is gaining 100% of the width as it should but the first element is hidden and there is no flex-wrap at all.

```css
#elegantImg{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.elegant-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.col {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.background {
    background-color: #F6F4F1;
    height: 100%;
}

.col img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .col {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
        <section>
            <div class="elegant-container">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="background"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <img id="elegantImg" src="https://i.imgur.com/TVL0phR.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Please, help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the aspect-ratio of the column element to apply height, based on the width. Also, remove the styling by id - it is not needed. Change your code to this:

```css
.elegant-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.col {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.background {
    background-color: #F6F4F1;
    height: 100%;
}

.col img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .col {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
        <section>
            <div class="elegant-container">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="background"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/TVL0phR.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: ibasi manqka lek

Answer (score 1):

Change your media query to this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .col {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
    }
    .elegant-container {
      height:170vw;
    }
}
```

That height is my rough estimate of double your image height relative to the viewport width. The issue is that when the divs are side-by-side, the inherent width of the window is giving width: 50% a meaning. But when they are set to vertical, there is no inherent height to the .elegant-container element, and the only element with a defined size is the image. Flex elements stretch to the size of their children if no size is given, so it needs to get the heights of its children to calculate that size. 50% of 0 is 0, so the .background column gets no height. Only after that is the height of .elegant-container calculated based on the image height, at which point the .background column is already set to a height of 0.

Just think of it like you have to stretch the container out to a size where the full image will fit and the .background column will be equal in size.

Comment: Hey, ty. But how did you calculate that the height should be 170vw?

Comment: No prob! Just guess and checked until it looked like the image wasn't getting cut off. Codepen is a great tool for quickly testing CSS ideas.

Answer (score -1):

```css
#elegantImg{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.elegant-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.col {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.background {
    background-color: #F6F4F1;
    height: 100%;
}

.col img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .col {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
        <section>
            <div class="elegant-container">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="background"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <img id="elegantImg" src="https://i.imgur.com/TVL0phR.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: They dont keep the same size when resizing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```css
#elegantImg{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.elegant-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.col {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.background {
    background-color: #F6F4F1;
    height: 100%;
}

.col img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .col {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .background{
        min-height: 300px;
    }
}
```

```html
        <section>
            <div class="elegant-container">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="background"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <img id="elegantImg" src="https://i.imgur.com/TVL0phR.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Almost what i want but the div with backgound color is not the same size as the div with the img when they collapse to a new line